How to airdrop to a randomly generated keypair for tests?
#[test]
fn test_create_user_pda() {
    let wallet = solana_sdk::signer::keypair::Keypair::new();

I want to use this wallet as a payer, how do I make an airdrop in a test?
Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit


For those who need this functionality, the only solution that actually worked for me was to spawning a new process executing solana airdrop command inside a test:
Command::new("solana")
        .arg("airdrop")
        .arg("--commitment")
        .arg("finalized")
        .arg("1")
        .arg(format!("{}", wallet_pubkey.to_string()))
        .spawn()
        .unwrap()
        .wait()
        .unwrap();

--commitment finalized will take more time than normally, but it's essential - otherwise we move on before the account is created.
For whatever reason, calling airdrop via RPC client with the same commitment config didn't actually wait for the transaction to finalize.

Calling airdrop with the RPC client returns a signature -- you then need to call confirm_transaction with that signature.

You cant fund a wallet and use it to sign the same tx its being funded in.
